# How to define a time-distance function for the Traveling Salesman algorithm

Tags: algorithm, traveling-salesman

I wrote a program that solves the traveling salesman problem minimizing the travel distance.
Now I'm triyng to create a weight function that takes distance and time and outputs a value I can use instead of the distance for the TSP.
My idea is to let the user input a percentage (like 70%) and weight the distance and time somehow.

The problem is I've no idea how to compare distance in meters with time in seconds.

Comment: Distance is converted to time using speed. For a fixed speed V, distance D will be covered in D/V time units

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to go is to specify a generalized cost function, i.e. you determine the costs (in monetary units) for one distance unit AND the costs for one time unit. For example, if your traveling salesman is a real traveling salesman then costs_per_time_unit could be approximated with wage_per_time_unit and cost_per_distance_unit with fuel_cost_per_distance_unit + ...

This yields c_generalized = cost_per_time_unit * time + cost_per_distance_unit * distance and you are done.